# "left- and right-hand side" vs. "left and right-hand side"

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to find the correct way between

*"left- and right-hand side"* or  *"left and right-hand side"*.

Comment: Left and right hand side, OR, left-hand side and right-hand side; not Left-. This is what I feel

Comment: This has been answered previously. Links are given in https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/545367/using-multiple-hyphens-in-a-phrase/545372#545372

Comment: @RamPillai - A suspended hyphen (e.g. `left-`) may be used when a single base word is used with separate, consecutive, hyphenated words that are connected by "and", "or", or "to". This usage is specifically recommended in some style guides

Comment: @MichaelHarvey; :)